# How to set text content of amp-selector into amp-state

Tags: amp-html, amp-bind

I would like to know how can I get the text content based on the option which a user selected and set it to `amp-state`.
For example, if a user selects "red" option. I want to set the "rouge" into `amp-state` not "red". I know that I can get `value` by event.targetOption inside setState function. However, could not find how to get and set text into `amp-state`.

```
<amp-state id="selectedColor">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
        "value": ""
    }
    </script>
</amp-state>

<p>Selected Color <span [text]="selectedColor.value"></span></p>

<amp-selector
  layout="container"
  on="select:AMP.setState({
        selectedColor: {
          value: event.targetOption
        }
      })">
  <div option="red">rouge</div> <!-- user select this -->
  <div option="blue">bleu</div>
  <div option="green">vert</div>
</amp-selector>
```

My expected output is as below

```
<p>Selected Color <span>rouge</span></p>
```

not

```
<p>Selected Color <span>red</span></p>
```

Comment: Why not set the option `option="red"` to `option="rouge"`?

Comment: The reason is the value which is selected will be used for search query and in my case I need to show text in Japanese which is multibyte characters. Also in my use case, I need to get the value from API with using amp-list. Just to simplify. I used French color words. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```html
<!-- 1. Initialize colorMap -->
<amp-state id="colorMap">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "red": "rouge",
      "blue": "bleu",
      "green": "vert"
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>

<!-- 2. On select: set new state of selectedColor -->
<amp-selector
  layout="container"
  on="select:AMP.setState({selectedColor: event.targetOption})">
  <div option="red">rouge</div>
  <div option="blue">bleu</div>
  <div option="green">vert</div>
</amp-selector>

<!-- 3. Bind the selectedColor value as identifier for the colorMap -->
<p>Selected Color <span [text]="colorMap[selectedColor]"></span></p>
```

1. Initialize `colorMap` as predefined `<amp-state>`
2. On select: set new state of the `selectedColor` as a single string (not an object with key: value)
3. Bind the `selectedColor` value as identifier for the `colorMap`

Note that the values ​​of the color map and the selector must be identical. I would prefer to use a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by setting amp-bind on each option.

```
<amp-state id="selectedColor">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
        "value": "",
        "text": ""
    }
    </script>
</amp-state>

<p>Selected Color <span [text]="selectedColor.value"></span></p>

<amp-selector
  layout="container"
  on="select:AMP.setState({
        selectedColor: {
          value: event.targetOption
        }
      })">
  <div option="red"
    on="tap:AMP.setState({
        selectedColor: {
          text: rouge
        }
      })">rouge</div> <!-- user select this -->
  <div option="blue"
    on="tap:AMP.setState({
        selectedColor: {
          text: bleu
        }
      })">bleu</div>
  <div option="green"
    on="tap:AMP.setState({
        selectedColor: {
          text: vert
        }
      })"
    >vert</div>
</amp-selector>
```